# Grunt: No file created And Cannot read property '0' of null Errors

Tags: gruntjs

I`m trying to configer Gruntfile.js as below, however when i run my build task My dist/scripts/main.css remains empty plus i get the following errors:

```
    PS D:\programming\web\grunt-portfolio> grunt build
    Running "clean:build" (clean) task
    >> 0 paths cleaned.

    Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

    √ No problems


    Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
    Configuration changed for concat, uglify, cssmin

    Running "concat:dist" (concat) task

    Running "concat:generated" (concat) task

    Running "cssmin:dist" (cssmin) task
    >> No files created.

    Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
    >> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    Warning: CSS minification failed at .tmp/concat/styles/main.css. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

Result: inside dist folder i have scripts and styles both have main.js & main.css with filerev stamps but the main.css is empty while main.js has its contents.

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
        require('time-grunt')(grunt);

        // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
        require('jit-grunt')(grunt,{
            useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
        });

        // Define the configuration for all the tasks
        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

            // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
            jshint: {
                options: {
                  jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                  reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
                },

                all: {
                  src: [
                    'Gruntfile.js',
                    'app/src/{,*/}*.js'
                  ]
                }
            },

            useminPrepare: {
              html: 'app/index.html',
              options: {
                dest: 'dist'
              }
            },

            // Concat
            concat: {
              options: {
                separator: ';'
              },

              // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
              dist: {}
            },

            // Uglify
            uglify: {
              // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
              dist: {}
            },

            cssmin: {
              dist: {}
            },

            // Filerev
            filerev: {
              options: {
                encoding: 'utf8',
                algorithm: 'md5',
                length: 20
              },

              release: {
                // filerev:release hashes(md5) all assets (images, js and css )
                // in dist directory
                files: [{
                  src: [
                    'dist/scripts/*.js',
                    'dist/styles/*.css',
                  ]
                }]
              }
            },

            // Usemin
            // Replaces all assets with their revved version in html and css files.
            // options.assetDirs contains the directories for finding the assets
            // according to their relative paths
            usemin: {
              html: ['dist/*.html'],
              css: ['.tmp/styles/*.css'],
              options: {
                assetsDirs: ['dist', 'dist/styles']
              }
            },

            copy: {
              dist: {
                cwd: 'app',
                src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!src/**/*.js' ],
                dest: 'dist',
                expand: true
              },

              fonts: {
                files: [
                  {
                    //for bootstrap fonts
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: 'lib/bootstrap/dist',
                    src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                    dest: 'dist'
                  }, {
                    //for font-awesome
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: 'fonts/font-awesome',
                    src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                    dest: 'dist'
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            watch: {
              copy: {
                files: [ 'app/**', '!app/**/*.css', '!app/**/*.js'],
                tasks: [ 'build' ]
              },

              scripts: {
                files: ['app/src/**.js'],
                tasks:[ 'build']
              },

              styles: {
                files: ['app/styles/style.css'],
                tasks:['build']
              },

              livereload: {
                options: {
                  livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },

                files: [
                  'app/{,*/}*.html',
                  '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                  'app/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
              }
            },

            connect: {
              options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
              },

              dist: {
                options: {
                  open: true,
                  base:{
                    path: 'dist',
                    options: {
                      index: 'index.html',
                      maxAge: 300000
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            clean: {
              build: {
                src: [ 'dist/']
              }
            }
        });

        grunt.registerTask('build', [
          'clean',
          'jshint',
          'useminPrepare',
          'concat',
          'cssmin',
          'uglify',
          'copy',
          'filerev',
          'usemin'
        ]);
        grunt.registerTask('serve',['build','connect:dist','watch']);
        grunt.registerTask('default',['build']);

};
```

I tried to run every thing inside the build task individually then noticed that the problem is in 'cssmin'  also noticed that with 'useminPrepare' I get a popup alert saying 'queue overflowed'.

lastly: package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.10.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

And in case it is helpful here is grunt.log:

```
        Initializing
    Command-line options: --verbose

    Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

    Registering Gruntfile tasks.
    Reading package.json...OK
    Parsing package.json...OK
    Initializing config...OK
    Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
    + build, default, serve

    Running tasks: build:dist

    Running "build:dist" (build) task

    Loading "grunt-contrib-clean" plugin

    Registering "D:\programming\web\grunt-portfolio\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean\tasks" tasks.
    Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
    + clean

    Running "clean" task

    Running "clean:build" (clean) task
    Verifying property clean.build exists in config...OK
    Files: [no src]
    Options: force=false, no-write=false
    >> 0 paths cleaned.

    Loading "grunt-contrib-jshint" plugin

    Registering "D:\programming\web\grunt-portfolio\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\tasks" tasks.
    Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
    + jshint

    Running "jshint" task

    Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
    Verifying property jshint.all exists in config...OK
    Files: Gruntfile.js, app/src/app.module.js, app/src/public/public.module.js, app/src/public/public.routes.js, app/src/services/awards.service.js, app/src/services/projects.service.js
    Options: force=false, reporter={}, reporterOutputRelative, jshintrc=".jshintrc"

    ÔêÜ No problems


    Loading "grunt-usemin" plugin

    Registering "D:\programming\web\grunt-portfolio\node_modules\grunt-usemin\tasks" tasks.
    Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
    + usemin, useminPrepare

    Running "useminPrepare" task

    Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
    Verifying property useminPrepare.html exists in config...OK
    Files: app/index.html -> html
    Options: root="app", dest="dist"
    Going through app/index.html to update the config
    Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

    Configuration is now:

      concat:
      { options: { separator: [32m';'[39m },
      dist: {},
      generated: 
       { files: 
          [ { dest: [32m'.tmp\\concat\\styles\\main.css'[39m,
              src: 
               [ [32m'app\\lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap-theme.min.css'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\fonts\\Shrikhand\\Shrikhand-Regular.ttf'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\fonts\\spac3-tech\\Spac3-tech.ttf'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\fonts\\digital-tech\\digital-tech.otf'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\fonts\\gtek-tech\\gtek-tech.ttf'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\fonts\\great-vibes\\great-vibes.ttf'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\fonts\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\lightbox\\dist\\css\\lightbox.min.css'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\styles\\style.css'[39m ] },
            { dest: [32m'.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\main.js'[39m,
              src: 
               [ [32m'app\\lib\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\bootstrap\\dist\\js\\bootstrap.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\lightbox\\dist\\js\\lightbox.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\emailJs\\email.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\angular\\angular.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\angular-ui-router\\release\\angular-ui-router.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\angular-sanitize\\angular-sanitize.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\angular-animate\\angular-animate.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\lib\\angular-bootstrap\\ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\app.module.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\public.module.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\public.routes.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\services\\projects.service.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\services\\awards.service.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\home\\home.controller.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\about\\about.controller.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\projects\\projects.controller.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\contact\\contact.controller.js'[39m,
                 [32m'app\\src\\public\\awards\\awards.controller.js'[39m ] } ] } }

      uglify:
      { dist: {},
      generated: 
       { files: 
          [ { dest: [32m'dist\\scripts\\main.js'[39m,
              src: [ [32m'.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\main.js'[39m ] } ] } }

      cssmin:
      { dist: {},
      generated: 
       { files: 
          [ { dest: [32m'dist\\styles\\main.css'[39m,
              src: [ [32m'.tmp\\concat\\styles\\main.css'[39m ] } ] } }

    Loading "grunt-contrib-concat" plugin

    Registering "D:\programming\web\grunt-portfolio\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\tasks" tasks.
    Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
    + concat

    Running "concat" task

    Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
    Verifying property concat.dist exists in config...OK
    File: [no files]
    Options: separator=";", banner="", footer="", stripBanners=false, process=false, sourceMap=false, sourceMapName=undefined, sourceMapStyle="embed"

    Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
    Verifying property concat.generated exists in config...OK
    Files: app/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css, app/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css, app/fonts/Shrikhand/Shrikhand-Regular.ttf, app/fonts/spac3-tech/Spac3-tech.ttf, app/fonts/digital-tech/digital-tech.otf, app/fonts/gtek-tech/gtek-tech.ttf, app/fonts/great-vibes/great-vibes.ttf, app/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css, app/lib/lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.min.css, app/styles/style.css -> .tmp\concat\styles\main.css
    Files: app/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js, app/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js, app/lib/lightbox/dist/js/lightbox.min.js, app/lib/emailJs/email.min.js, app/lib/angular/angular.min.js, app/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js, app/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js, app/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js, app/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js, app/src/app.module.js, app/src/public/public.module.js, app/src/public/public.routes.js, app/src/services/projects.service.js, app/src/services/awards.service.js, app/src/public/home/home.controller.js, app/src/public/about/about.controller.js, app/src/public/projects/projects.controller.js, app/src/public/contact/contact.controller.js, app/src/public/awards/awards.controller.js -> .tmp\concat\scripts\main.js
    Options: separator=";", banner="", footer="", stripBanners=false, process=false, sourceMap=false, sourceMapName=undefined, sourceMapStyle="embed"
    Reading app/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css...OK
    Reading app/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css...OK
    Reading app/fonts/Shrikhand/Shrikhand-Regular.ttf...OK
    Reading app/fonts/spac3-tech/Spac3-tech.ttf...OK
    Reading app/fonts/digital-tech/digital-tech.otf...OK
    Reading app/fonts/gtek-tech/gtek-tech.ttf...OK
    Reading app/fonts/great-vibes/great-vibes.ttf...OK
    Reading app/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css...OK
    Reading app/lib/lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.min.css...OK
    Reading app/styles/style.css...OK
    Writing .tmp\concat\styles\main.css...OK
    File .tmp\concat\styles\main.css created.Reading app/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/lightbox/dist/js/lightbox.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/emailJs/email.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/angular/angular.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js...OK
    Reading app/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js...OK
    Reading app/src/app.module.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/public.module.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/public.routes.js...OK
    Reading app/src/services/projects.service.js...OK
    Reading app/src/services/awards.service.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/home/home.controller.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/about/about.controller.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/projects/projects.controller.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/contact/contact.controller.js...OK
    Reading app/src/public/awards/awards.controller.js...OK
    Writing .tmp\concat\scripts\main.js...OK
    File .tmp\concat\scripts\main.js created.
    Loading "grunt-contrib-cssmin" plugin

    Registering "D:\programming\web\grunt-portfolio\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\tasks" tasks.
    Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
    + cssmin

    Running "cssmin" task

    Running "cssmin:dist" (cssmin) task
    Verifying property cssmin.dist exists in config...OK
    File: [no files]
    >> No files created.

    Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
    Verifying property cssmin.generated exists in config...OK
    Files: .tmp/concat/styles/main.css -> dist\styles\main.css
    Options: rebase=false, report="min", sourceMap=false
    >> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    Warning: CSS minification failed at .tmp/concat/styles/main.css. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2016-12-19 08:33:03 UTC-0)
    loading tasks                  67ms  ÔûêÔûê 5%
    loading grunt-contrib-clean    33ms  Ôûê 2%
    clean:build                     0ms  0%
    loading grunt-contrib-jshint  172ms  ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê 13%
    jshint:all                    219ms  ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê 16%
    loading grunt-usemin           47ms  ÔûêÔûê 4%
    useminPrepare:html             47ms  ÔûêÔûê 4%
    loading grunt-contrib-concat   31ms  Ôûê 2%
    concat:dist                     0ms  0%
    concat:generated               47ms  ÔûêÔûê 4%
    loading grunt-contrib-cssmin  156ms  ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê 12%
    cssmin:dist                     0ms  0%
    cssmin:generated              516ms  ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê 39%
    Total 1.3s
```

My css file as requested:

```
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        line-height: 2;
        background:  #2D2D2D center/100% url('../images/background/gray5.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: cover;
    }


    /*navigation*/ 
    .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse,
    .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
    .container>.navbar-collapse,
    .container>.navbar-header {
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
    .navbar-brand > img {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 60px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {
        color:#FFF;
    }
    /* .navbar-nav > ul {
        margin: 0 auto;
    } */
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
        color: #8EE8CD;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
        background: rgb(14, 78, 114);
    }

    /* Content style*/
    .container.content {
        margin-top: 100px;
        max-width: 90%;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 170px);
    }
    /* Pages headers */
    .home h1,
    .projects h1,
    .about h1,
    .contact h1,
    .awards h1 {
        font-family: 'Spac3-tech';
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 200%;
        color:#8ef4ff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    footer {
        max-height: 50px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgb(14, 78, 114);
    }

    /* Home */
    .home {
        text-align: center;
        color:#FFF;
    }
    .home h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Spac3-tech';
        font-size: 150%;
    }
    .home #build {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 48%;
        min-width: 20%;
        margin: 0.75em;
    }

    /* Gallery for projects and awards */
    .tab-content .thumbnails img {
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .tab-content:hover .thumbnails img {
        opacity: 0.6;
        transform: scale(0.90);
    }
    .tab-content .thumbnails:hover .thumbnail {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .tab-content .thumbnails img:hover {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(2deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    /* nav-tabs for projects and awards */
    .nav-tabs {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #8EE8CD;
        border-radius: 5%;
        background-color: rgb(14, 78, 114);
    }
    .nav-tabs> li> a {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        color: #8EE8CD;
        border: 1px dotted #8EE8CD;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-tabs>li.active>a,
    .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
    .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #8EE8CD;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    /* Projects & Awards*/
    .projects, .awards {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .projects-content, .awards-content {
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .projects-content img.thumbnail,
    .awards-content img.thumbnail {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .projects-content .project-column.well,
    .awards-content .award-column.well   {
        background: #73A6E4;
        border-radius: 5%;
    }

    /* About */

    .about img.thumbnail {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px;
        display: block;
    }
    .about .jumbotron {
        padding: 0;
        border: 5px solid  #73A6E4;
    }
    .about .panel-primary .panel-heading {
        background: #73A6E4;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .about .panel-title {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .about a.accordion-toggle{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .about ul.panel-body {
        list-style-type: none;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li{
        width:80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(1) {  /* html */
        background-color: rgba(241, 101, 41, 0.8); 
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(2) {  /* css */
        background-color: rgba(48, 173, 217, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(3) {  /* bootstrap */
        background-color: rgba(95, 63, 139, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(4) {  /* js */
        background-color: rgba(251, 182, 2, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(5) {  /* jquery */
        background-color: rgba(8, 104, 171, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(6) {  /* angular */
        background-color: rgba(253, 0, 33, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(7) {  /* processingJs */
        background-color:rgba(29, 104, 146, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(8) {  /* github */
        background-color: rgba(13, 38, 54, 0.4);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(9) {  /* nodeJs */
        background-color: rgba(140, 200, 75, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(10) { /* mongoDB */
        background-color: rgba(88, 170, 80, 0.8);
    }
    .about ul.panel-body li:nth-child(11) { /* task runners */
        background-color: rgba(251, 169, 25, 0.8);
    }
    .about p {
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    /* Contact */
    form {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        background: #73A6E4;
        padding: 20px 25px;
        margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 5%;
    }
    form > h2 {
        color: rgb(28, 31, 78);
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
    }
    form input,
    form textarea {
      font: inherit;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: lightyellow;
    }
    form button {
        margin-top: -50px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        padding: 5px 20px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background:  #3072AB;
        color: white;
    }
    form label {
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin-bottom: 1px;
      display: block;
    }






    /*************              *************
        ********* Media Queries *********
    ****************************************/

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1824px) and (orientation : portrait) { 


        /*navigation*/ 
        .navbar-brand > img {
            width: 1.5em;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            min-width: 60px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        ul.navbar-nav {
          list-style-type: none;
          text-align: center;
          float: none;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li {
          margin: 0 auto;
          max-width: 100;
          width: 17%;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li:first-child {
            margin-left: 10%;
        } 
        .container.content {
            width: auto;
            max-width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        /* Pages headers */


        .home h1,
        .projects h1,
        .about h1,
        .contact h1,
        .awards h1 {
            font-size: 3.5em;
        }

         /* Home */
        .home #build {
            min-width: 25%;
            width: 40%;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 2em;
        }
        .home h2 {
            font-size: 2.7em;
        }
        .home p {
            font-size: 1.9em;
        } 

    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1824px) and (orientation : landscape) {
            .navbar-brand > img {
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            min-width: 60px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        ul.navbar-nav {
          list-style-type: none;
          text-align: center;
          float: none;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li {
          margin: 0 auto;
          max-width: 100;
          width: 17%;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li:first-child {
            margin-left: 10%;
        }

        /* Pages headers */
        .home h1,
        .projects h1,
        .about h1,
        .contact h1,
        .awards h1 {
            font-size: 3.2em;
        }

         /* Home */
        .home #build {
            min-width: 25%;
            width: 30%;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 2em;
        }
        .home h2 {
            font-size: 2.5em;
        }
        .home p {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        } 

        form {
            max-width: 80%;
        }

    }



     @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .navbar-brand > img {
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            min-width: 60px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        ul.navbar-nav {
          list-style-type: none;
          text-align: center;
          float: none;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li {
          margin: 0 auto;
          max-width: 100;
          width: 17%;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li:first-child {
            margin-left: 10%;
        }

        /* Pages headers */
        .home h1,
        .projects h1,
        .about h1,
        .contact h1,
        .awards h1 {
            font-size: 2.8em;
        }

         /* Home */
        .home #build {
            min-width: 20%;
            width: 25%;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 1.5em;
        }
        .home h2 {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
        .home p {
            font-size: 1.3em;
        } 
        form {
            max-width: 70%;
        }   
     }



     @media (min-width: 1441px) {
        .navbar-brand > img {
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            min-width: 60px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        ul.navbar-nav {
          list-style-type: none;
          text-align: center;
          float: none;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li {
          margin: 0 auto;
          max-width: 100;
          width: 17%;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        ul.navbar-nav > li:first-child {
            margin-left: 10%;
        }
        .container.content {
            width: auto;
            max-width: 90%;
            padding: 60px;
        }
        .home #build {
            min-width: 20%;
            width: 30%;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 2em;
        }
        .projects, .awards {
            max-width: 150%;
        }
        .col-xl-3 {
            width: 25%;
        }

        form {
            max-width: 60%;
        }
    }
```

Inside  index.html file i included:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->... css files ...<!-- endbuild --> <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->... js files ...<!-- endbuild -->
```

please note that I`m using bootstrap.min.css,bootstrap-theme.min.css,  lightbox.min.css and some fonts too.

Comment: My guess is there is something in your css file that cssmin doesnt like: .tmp/concat/styles/main.css. Try change any "//" comments to "/* */" as suggested here https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/480 if that doesnt help can you post your css file?

Comment: ok i dont have any // as i found link too and changed them all. ill post my file now